# How can we get the cost of an Azure VM in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to find out how we can get the cost of the different Azure VM sizes in c#. I'm able to get a list of all the different sizes but not able to get the cost. For example, my VM is a General Purpose B2s VM which is shown as $40.30 in the Azure portal. I've not found a way to get this cost in C#. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use the Azure Retail Prices API additionally to query detailed VM prices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

Comment: Thanks for this. Managed to get the information I needed.